# Trying to cluster close delivery places keeping constraints on time and order amount?

Tags: python, r, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing

I am trying to assign societies to a delivery truck. A truck can take a limited load and has limited time. A society has a delivery time. I also have travel time between warehouse (truck departs from here only) and a data frame that has travel time from every society to other society.

Code runs fine but takes a lot of time when data is big. There can be an easy way for this?

1 truck max load : 350 orders.

1 truck max time to deliver : 135 minutes

Below are the data tables.

Order_Count : Number of orders in society

warehouse_time : Travel time from warehouse to Society

DeliveryTime : Time to deliver orders in society.

```
Society_ID  Order_Count warehouse_time  DeliveryTime
    1   305            1722             4122
    2   168            1409             4557
    3   231            1331             7026
    7   216            1466             4684
    8   212            1202             3929
    9   65             1050             2341
    10  59             1355             2580
    11  199            1417             4957
    12  54             1380             1352
    14  117            1498             3388
```

The other data frame has travel time from each society.

```
s1  s2  Time
1   1   0
2   1   914
3   1   898
7   1   1000
8   1   1024
9   1   1044
10  1   1140
11  1   1173
12  1   822
14  1   1013
1   2   907
2   2   0
3   2   1076
7   2   1054
8   2   1013
9   2   1033
10  2   623
11  2   656
12  2   804
14  2   1173
1   3   675
2   3   824
3   3   0
7   3   514
8   3   633
9   3   653
10  3   1049
11  3   1083
12  3   296
14  3   633
1   7   767
2   7   958
3   7   507
7   7   0
8   7   768
9   7   787
10  7   1184
11  7   1217
12  7   431
14  7   604
1   8   1009
2   8   1159
3   8   896
7   8   875
8   8   0
9   8   303
10  8   1384
11  8   1417
12  8   631
14  8   994
1   9   903
2   9   1052
3   9   790
7   9   769
8   9   131
9   9   0
10  9   1278
11  9   1311
12  9   525
14  9   888
1   10  900
2   10  661
3   10  1069
7   10  1048
8   10  1006
9   10  1026
10  10  0
11  10  242
12  10  798
14  10  1167
1   11  963
2   11  723
3   11  1131
7   11  1110
8   11  1069
9   11  1089
10  11  261
11  11  0
12  11  860
14  11  1229
1   12  562
2   12  711
3   12  744
7   12  723
8   12  681
9   12  701
10  12  937
11  12  970
12  12  0
14  12  842
1   14  805
2   14  990
3   14  539
7   14  654
8   14  799
9   14  819
10  14  1221
11  14  1254
12  14  463
14  14  0
```

Currently I have written a logic but it takes time when the data size increases. Below is the code for the same.

```
# stored the order count, if exceeding 350 then find remainder 
orderCount  = defaultdict( lambda: 0 )

# will store how many fully loaded trucks shall be sent to society with 350 orders
fullyLoadedTrucks = defaultdict( lambda: 0 )

for index, row in wdf.iterrows():
    orderCount[row['Society_ID']] = (int(row['Order_Count']))

# implementation of above mentioned comments.
for i in orderCount:
    if orderCount[i] > maxOrderCount:
        fullyLoadedTrucks[i] = orderCount[i]// maxOrderCount
        orderCount[i] %= maxOrderCount

# quotient = no. of fully loaded truck for eg. OrderCount for some society id = 1225, then we need to send 3 
#fullyloaded trucks and one partially filled with 175 orders 1225//350 = 3, 1225 % 350 = 175


# time spent from going from wh to society
timeFromWH   = OrderedDict()

# time spent during delivery within the society
deliveryTime = dict()


for _, row in wdf.iterrows():
    sid = int(row['Society_ID'])
    timeFromWH[sid] = int(row['total_time'])

    deliveryTime[sid] = int(row['Delivery_Time'])

for _, row in sdf.iterrows():
    sid = int(row['society_1'])
    sdf.at[_, 'Time'] =  deliveryTime[sid] + int(row['Time'])
    # set 'time' of i'th society equal to time spent in delivering goods in that society + time spent on traveling

sdf.head()

time = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
for _, row in sdf.iterrows():
    _from = int(row['society_2'])
    _to = int(row['society_1'])
    if _from == _to: continue
    time[_from][_to] = int(row['Time'])                     
    # MOST IMPORTANT: if we decide to go from society x to y then how much time will we require on travel and delivering goods in society y,
    # NOTE: we don't consider the time spent in societey x in time[x][y], we assume we have already somehow reached x
    # this loop is the reason why overall time complexity of this code reaches O(n**2)

visited = defaultdict(lambda : False) # No society is visited
CountOfVisited = 0 # initially 0 societies are visited
path = defaultdict(lambda : [])
truck = 1 # This variable will give the total number of trucks required
truckNumber = defaultdict(lambda: []) # This dict will store the trucknumber of i'th society
truckOrder = defaultdict(lambda: [])
considered = defaultdict(lambda: True)

while CountOfVisited != len(wdf):
    # until all societies are visited
    if not len(timeFromWH): break
    society, timereq = timeFromWH.popitem(last=False)     
    '''  ^^^^^^
    pops out closest society and timereq for both: going from warehouse to the society and delivering goods in the society 

    '''
    while visited[society]:
        society, timereq = timeFromWH.popitem(last=False)    # closest society has already been visited then find next closest

    if timereq > maxTime or orderCount[society]>maxOrderCount:           
        # if total time required is more than MaxTime, then we don't consider going to this society
        considered[society] = False
        visited[society] = True
        truckNumber[society] = -1  # not considering
        truckOrder[society ] = -1  # not considering
        CountOfVisited += 1
        continue

    ordersf = orderCount[society]
    timesf = timereq               # we went to closest society and time_so_far = delivery time + travel time
    queue = 1                      # this society is where the truck shall go first (truck Order)
    while timesf < maxTime and ordersf < maxOrderCount: 
        # if we have more time left then continue finding the closest society and deliver goods.
        visited[society] = True    # mark as current society visited
        CountOfVisited  += 1

        truckNumber[society] = truck    
        truckOrder[society]  = queue
        queue += 1

        society, timreq = time[society].popitem(last=False)
        while visited[society]:
            society, timereq = time[society].popitem(last=False) #find next closest and repeat.
        timesf += timereq
        ordersf += orderCount[society]

    # if we are here, then truck went back from societies due to time limit, and we need to send other trucks there to
    # deliver goods and hence increment the truck number by one and repeat this whole process
    truck += 1
```

Below is the desired output which says. This society is assigned this truck.

```
Society_ID  Order_Count warehouse_time  DeliveryTime  Truck
    1   305            1722             4122        1
    2   168            1409             4557        2
    3   231            1331             7026        3
    7   216            1466             4684        4
    8   212            1202             3929        5
    9   65             1050             2341        2
    10  59             1355             2580        2
    11  199            1417             4957        6
    12  54             1380             1352        3
    14  117            1498             3388        4
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I am working on a model that finds the best route to deliver a product. I have distance of places where the product has to be delivered. The first fleet leaves from a warehouse . The fleet must reach the nearest drop location (say S1) and then from S1 it must again find the nearest drop location.

Comment: You say the code runs fine, but is it the time it takes which is your concern?

Comment: yes..also I feel there can be a optimal way to do this

Comment: Your question might be better off at [`codereview.stackexchange.com`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) perhaps; I've never posted there, although I think it's focus is more on making working code work better.